# Errors when importing database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, import, phpmyadmin, xampp

When i try to import my DB i get this error. I don't know what I should do, please help.

--

### -- Database: `oddjobexchange`

--

### -- ---------------------------------------------------- --

--
TABLE structure FOR TABLE `admin` --
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
`Email` varchar( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`Password` varchar( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `Email` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;

MySQL said: Documentation

### #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table structure for table `admin`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `Em' at line 10

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the follwing to top of file.

CREATE DATABASE databasename;
USE databasename;

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be a space after the first two dashes. Otherwise it is not a valid comment:

```
------------------------------------------------------ --
```

should be:

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------- --
```

Comment: unfortunatly yes. I made the database in phpmyadmin, but it needs to be put on a disk and imported so i exported the sql file, tried the import (stupidly thinking it would work) but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure the database exists on the new host?